# What id is need in this SQL to show the student info from table?

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php

// Check existence of id parameter before processing further
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){

// Include config file
require_once 'connection.php';

// Prepare a select statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = ?";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {

    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);

    // Set parameters
    $param_id = trim($_GET["id"]);

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            // Retrieve individual field value
            $name = $row["name"];
            $lname = $row["lname"];
            $fnumber = $row["fnumber"];
        } else {
            // URL doesn't contain valid id parameter. Redirect to index page
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }

    } else {
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
} else{
// URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
header("location: index.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

I have table with all the students and some information about them,my task is when submit the read button of the table to show only the information of the current student,but i can't catch the student id to complete it for any student. I want to take some variable in the SQL which will work for any student from the table .

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, you already seem to have an id for a specific student? Does that code work? If not, what doesn't?

Comment: @DsRaj Don't blindly take parameters in your query, at least validate/sanitize them before.

Comment: @DsRaj Are you seriously suggesting the OP add an SQL Injection vector to their code ???????????????????

Comment: I use CRUD table,i log with admin user and I want to show the information of the student in view page when click the read button for the student

Answer (score 0):

**change this 2 line**

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
$param_id = trim($_GET["id"]);
```

**TO**

```
$param_id = trim($_GET["id"]);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything